# Redundant security by deleting protected params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

In Rails 3, we can define the accessible attributes:

```
attr_accessible :rating, :review
```

In this model, there is additional `user_id` which is protected to prevent forgery/hacking. This value is assigned in the controller:

```
@review.user_id = current_user.id
```

If I use Firebug to manually include the `user_id`, it will be part of the `params[:review]`, but of course since `user_id` is not defined in the `attr_accessible`, it wouldn't get saved into the database. Such case is rather secure.

**Question 1**

I read in **Rails 3 In Action** book, Yehuda Katz included `.delete` method to delete unauthorized params before further action is performed: `params[:review].delete(:user_id)`. Should I include this as well to further secure my app, or just ignore this step?

**Question 2**

If I should include the method above, I would like to have something like `.delete_all_except` to just strip it to the allowed attributes in the params. How do I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If enabled, Rails 3.2 will through an exception if additional mass-assignment params are sent to the model

config/application.rb

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
```

Rather than deleting out parameters you don't want, I recommend only accepting parameters you do want:

```
@user.update_attributes params[:user].slice(:rating, :review)
```

This will only return the user params you allow.

note: in Rails 4 (coming soonish), this behavior is implemented with a DSL named [strong-parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters). You can install this gem in Rails 3.2 to implement now:

```
@user.update_attributes params.require(:user).permit(:rating, :review)
```

Comment: So it is still recommended to `slice` the wanted parameter even after `attr_accessible` is defined?

Comment: If you want an exception to occur, then don't slice the parameters.